# How to extend an ITK class in Python?

Tags: python, itk, image-registration

SimpleITK provides easy to use Python interface. Can I extend the class from there?

I need to solve a registration problem, which requires me to write my customized registration class, especially the similarity metric. How can I extend SimpleITK in Python for my use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SimpleElastix](http://github.com/kaspermarstal/SimpleElastix) package is an extension of SimpleITK that includes the elastix registration library in addition to the standard SimpleITK methods. You can write your metric in elastix and use SimpleElastix to wrap your metric in Python (or any of the other languages supported by SimpleITK). You would then use SimpleElastix to perform registration. To use your would-be metric in SimpleElastix:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

SimpleElastix = sitk.SimpleElastix()
SimpleElastix.SetParameter("Metric", "NameOfYourMetric")
SimpleElastix.SetFixedImage(sitk.ReadImage("fixedImage.nii"))
SimpleElastix.SetMovingImage(sitk.ReadImage("movingImage.nii"))
resultImage = SimpleElastix.Execute()
```

Elastix itself is an extension of ITK's v3 registration libraries, so if you are comfortable with ITK, the elastix codebase will not be alien to you. You can see how metrics are implemented by looking at the examples in the [src/Components/Metrics](https://github.com/mstaring/elastix/tree/master/src/Components/Metrics) directory. Take a look at the AdvancedMeanSqaures metric for instance. Basically you only need to modify the `GetValue()` and `GetValueAndDerivative()` functions  in the files prefixed with `itk` to implement your metric. You then need to modify the files prefixed with `elx` if you want to pass parameters to your metric via the parameter maps and the CMakeLists file to register the metric with the build system. Parameter maps are key-value pairs that allows you to configure registration components including your metric. You can read more about parameter maps in the [SimpleElastix documentation](http://simpleelastix.readthedocs.org/ParameterMaps.html) or [elastix manual](http://elastix.isi.uu.nl/download/elastix_manual_v4.8.pdf).

To wrap your metric with SimpleElastix, you clone [the repository](http://github.com/kaspermarstal/SimpleElastix) and follow the guide [how to build SimpleElastix manually](http://simpleelastix.readthedocs.org/GettingStarted.html#manually-building-on-linux) except you set `ELASTIX_DIR` to your modified version of elastix. The elastix build system will take care of wrapping your metric in elastix, and the SimpleElastix build system will take care of wrapping elastix in python.

Disclaimer: I am the author of SimpleElastix.

Comment: It sounds very close to what I'm looking for. Can you please elaborate more on how to wrap my own metric after implementing it (in C++, I assume)? Or can I directly implement the metric in Python? Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer with information on how to wrap your metric with SimpleElastix. With this approach you cannot implement your metric directly in python unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapped SimpleITK interface for Python does not provide an interface to extend from or derive from. The options for the SimpleITK ImageRegistrationMethods are the options available.

Deriving classes and tweaking algorithms is best done with ITK at the C++ level.

You may be able to put together a little registration framework with components of SimpleITK and Python. For example you could use the ResampleImageFilter and the Transform classes from SimpleITK along with a scipy optimizer and a custom metric.